# How to display one or the other information depending on the page number in XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using XSL-FO to create PDF's. Now I have a label that I want to display only on the first page, and another label that I want to display on all other pages, e.g.

#### Page 1

```
Last month's balance
```

#### Page 2 - n

```
Previous page's balance
```

The whole PDF is actually just a simple table, so this isn't about a cover page that stands outside of the data. How can I do it?

See also this related question: [How can I sum up some values per page in a table in XSL-FO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931266/how-can-i-sum-up-some-values-per-page-in-a-table-in-xsl-fo)

Comment: Can this label reside in a separate fo:region, or is it part of the table?

Comment: @Dabbler: The label can either be in the table header, or outside of the table in the page header. The overall layout is simple enough to live with both variants

Comment: If it's outside of the table, you can do it by switching the `fo:page-master` as Michael has meanwhile suggested. I don't currently see how that can work if the label is inside the table, though, which is why I asked whether it's in a separate region.

Comment: @Dabbler: OK, I understand. I'll have to play around with those suggestions. Looks like it's feasible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one can either be achieved using fo:marker and fo:retrieve-marker (from fo:static-content), or with the help of fo:page-sequence-master, that provides different fo:simple-page-master entries for the first page (@page-position="first") and other pages (="rest").

In the latter case you would need to name static regions on different simple-page-masters differently, and provide an fo:static-content in the fo:page-sequence for each page master.

Comment: The `<fo:marker/>` and `<fo:retrieve-marker>` solution worked for me. See my [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930833/how-to-display-one-or-the-other-information-depending-on-the-page-number-in-xsl/7951920#7951920)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried [Michael Sulyaev's suggestion about page-sequence-master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930833/how-to-display-one-or-the-other-information-depending-on-the-page-number-in-xsl#7933676) on this problem. However, using `<fo:marker/>` and `<fo:retrieve-marker/>` seemed to work. I'm not sure if this is a valid XSL-FO solution, but it works with Apache fop.

It seems to be important that the `<fo:retrieve-marker/>` is a `<fo:static-content/>` descendant, according to the [w3.org specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_retrieve-marker). It cannot be part of the table itself.

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
  <fo:table>
    <!-- Render <fo:table-column/> elements -->
    <xsl:call-template name="TableColumns"/>

    <!-- fo:table-body, fo:table-row, fo:table-cell, fo:block 
         omitted for the example -->
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="carryover-label"/>
  </fo:table>
</fo:static-content>
```

Then, the `<fo:marker/>` elements are positioned in the data table itself:

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
  <fo:table>
    <!-- Render the same <fo:table-column/> elements -->
    <xsl:call-template name="TableColumns"/>

    <fo:table-body>
      <xsl:for-each select="/data-path">
        <!-- fo:table-row, fo:table-cell, fo:block 
             omitted for the example -->
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="carryover-label">
              Last month's balance</fo:marker>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="carryover-label">
              Last page's balance</fo:marker>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</fo:flow>
```

Now the two tables only have to be positioned exactly one on top of the other. For my problem, that's a valid workaround.