# How can I sum up some values per page in a table in XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using XSL-FO to generate an account statement print out. The PDF is actually just a simple table with a simple header on every page. The difficulty is that I have to display transaction volumes per page, e.g.

#### Page 1

```
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Text                         | Credit    | Debit     | Balance             |
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Previous month               |           |           |           (*1) 1000 |
| abc                          |      1000 |           |                2000 |
| abc                          |           |       500 |                1500 |
| abc                          |           |       200 |                1300 |
| ...                          |           |           |                     |
| Carry over                   | (*2) 1000 |  (*3) 700 |           (*4) 1300 |
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

#### Page 2

```
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Text                         | Credit    | Debit     | Balance             |
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Previous page                | (*2) 1000 |  (*3) 700 |           (*4) 1300 |
| abc                          |      1000 |           |                2300 |
| abc                          |           |       500 |                1800 |
| abc                          |           |       200 |                1600 |
| ...                          |           |           |                     |
| Carry over                   | (*2) 2000 | (*3) 1400 |           (*4) 1600 |
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Here are some explanations:

1. This is the previous month's balance. It's pre-calculated and well-known as an XSL variable. No problem with that, that's a regular header (only on the first page)
2. This value is calculated on a per-page basis. It sums up all credit amounts on the same page. I can't calculate that myself, as I don't know when XSL-FO will do the page break. So I imagine XSL-FO must do the calculation for me. The sum at the bottom of a page is the same as the value at the top of the subsequent page.
3. This value is the same as 2, only for debit amounts.
4. This value is just the last transaction's balance at the bottom of a page. That value is repeated at the top of the next page.

How can I do these calculations with XSL-FO?

See also this related question: [How to display one or the other information depending on the page number in XSL-FO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930833/how-to-display-one-or-the-other-information-depending-on-the-page-number-in-xsl)

Comment: Have you looked at XSLT yet? You can write an XSLT stylesheet that contains/generates your FO elements, and it allows you to conduct any reasonable calculations.

Comment: @Dabbler: I'm using XSLT, I'm just not sure how I can make XSL-FO use calculated values on a per-page basis. I guess Michael's answer is valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ([at the time when I answered this question, it's no longer true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012095/521799)) fop doesn't implement `<fo:retrieve-table-marker/>` from what I have found out. Instead, this solution here worked for me:

[How to display one or the other information depending on the page number in XSL-FO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930833/how-to-display-one-or-the-other-information-depending-on-the-page-number-in-xsl/7951920#7951920)

It involves creating a separate table outside of the `<fo:flow/>` that displays the table header using `<fo:retrieve-marker/>` elements.

Comment: This may work for table header if the table is the first thing in the flow, but not for the table footer: we do not know beforehand where the table footer appears on the page.

Comment: @MichaelSulyaev: In principle, you're right. But my layout is expected to contain exactly 37 rows of fixed height. So I'm lucky :-) I can do the same trick with the footer also, and move the table footer into the `<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after"/>` section

Comment: @MichaelSulyaev... Hmm, actually I just now realise that the whole question becomes somewhat obsolete, as with this sort of fixed layout, I can do some calculations in XSL already before letting FOP run the layout...

Comment: Apache FOP now _does_ implement `retrieve-table-markers` with some limitations. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012095/3000316. It worked for me really well!

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic: Thanks for the hint. I've added the link to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try "table markers": http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_retrieve-table-marker.

In XSLT for each row inject a marker with the sum. Then let the engine select a marker to substitute for the fo:retrieve-table-marker in table header or footer. The idea is that proper marker will be selected at rendering time depending on the marker's position on the page and @retrieve-position and @retrieve-boundary on the fo:retrieve-table-marker.

Comment: That looks precisely like what I'm looking for. I'll try this ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the `<fo:retrieve-table-marker/>` implementation seems to be missing in Apache fop :-(. I'll have to play around with `<fo:retrieve-marker/>` instead