# XSL Table subtotal by page without fixed nr of row

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a table witch can use multiples pages, I would like to have a subtotal on every page.
I could get the subtotal until the page I'm looking at (with preceding-siblings) but not the total of the page itself.

I found a stackoverflow response ( [XSLT 1.0: Calculating Subtotal on each page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250383/xslt-1-0-calculating-subtotal-on-each-page) ) but it use a fixed number of row.
In my case i wont know how many row will be shown in advance, and the number can change between the pages.

some part of the xsl :

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
    <fo:block-container height="10mm">
        <xsl:variable name="vStart" ><fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="RunningSubTotal" 
                      retrieve-boundary="page" retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vEnd" ><fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="RunningSubTotal" 
                      retrieve-boundary="page" retrieve-position="last-ending-within-page" />
        </xsl:variable>
                    
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">vStart:<xsl:copy-of select="$vStart" /></fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">vEnd:<xsl:copy-of select="$vEnd" /></fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">diff (vEnd - vStart):</fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:static-content>
```

So:

- is there a way to have a sum of an unknown number of row ?
- is it possible to execute a subtraction between marker
- is there a way to know the number of row in a page ?

Comment: I see two options: 1. In xsl:fo try to calculate the number of rows that will fit in a page based on the content in those rows. 2. Do a post proces step on the intermediate result...if the xslf-fo processor support that

Comment: As each row is written, drop a marker with the subtotal. Then a carefully placed footer that mimics the table itself can show the subtotal.