# XSL-FO : Compute difference retrieve-marker

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have two retrieve-marker and I would like to subtract their result.

```
 <xsl:variable name="vStart" >
                            <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="RunningSubTotal" retrieve-boundary="page" retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="vEnd" ><fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="RunningSubTotal" retrieve-boundary="page" retrieve-position="last-ending-within-page" /></xsl:variable>

    <fo:block font-size="8pt">diff (vEnd - vStart):<xsl:value-of select="$vEnd - $vStart"/></fo:block><!-- THIS DO NOT WORK value is NaN-->
```

Is there a way to achieve what I need ?

Comment: You are thinking of the world backwards. XSL templates have no idea of page characteristics, XSL FO has no capabilities to do math because it is NOT XSL. You are trying to think that you could do MATH in XSL-FO derived from pages that do not exist in the XSL FO. So reformulate your question completely showing input XML and a picture of what you wish to try. You could do math in XSL that leaves markers all around relative to the last subtotal and then retrieves that, but without seeing what you want it's all a guess.

Comment: Thank Kevin for your answer :)

The goal that I want to achieve is described on this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77192868/xsl-table-subtotal-by-page-without-fixed-nr-of-row?noredirect=1#comment136094520_77192868

The xml I'm using is
```
<root>
 <employes>
  <employe>
   <firstName>Tin</firstName>
   <lastName>Tin</lastName>
   <dateOfBirth>05.07.1953</dateOfBirth>
   <salary>1</salary>
   <subTotalSalary>1</subTotalSalary>
  </employe>
                   ....
 </employes>
</root>
```

Comment: And I would like to have a footer on every page with the values subtotal = sum(preceding-sibling::employe[position()]/salary) + ./salary)   
and page subtotal = sum of salary shown only in the current page, without the preceding pages