# Easiest way to find the sum of the values in a table in XSL FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I want to sum the number column in a table,, I can't able to understand how can I do that in XSL FO? Can anyone explain me in an easy manner
Here is my XML input code:

```
<Studies>
<Study>
<name>name1</name>
<amount>500</amount>
<age>5</age>
</Study>
<Study>
<name>name1</name>
<amount>500</amount>
<age>15</age>
</Study>
<Study>
<name>name1</name>
<amount>500</amount>
<age>20</age>
</Study>
</studies>
```

I want the output as, Total:1500(ie., sum the amount)
see also this related question: [How can I sum up some values per page in a table in XSL-FO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931266/how-can-i-sum-up-some-values-per-page-in-a-table-in-xsl-fo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "sum the number column in a table"; you sum the numbers that go into the column. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Studies">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Study">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="amount"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(Study/amount)"/></td>
            </tr>               
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:
XML is case-sensitive: `</studies>` does **not** close `<Studies>`.