# xsl:fo retrieve-marker not valid child

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, marker

I need for my xsl:fo transformation an `<fo:retrieve-marker>` in an table but I don't know if this is possible because I use FOP Processor for my transformation.

If i use the `<fo:retrieve-marker>` in my table I always get an error message that the tag has to be in an static content.

Here is the table with the marker

```
                <xsl:call-template name="MMEL-Table-Header"/>

                <!-- Bottom table Line  -->
                <fo:table-footer>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>                                                                             
                            <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued"> <fo:inline>(continued)</fo:inline></fo:marker>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>

                </fo:table-footer>

                <fo:table-body >               

                    <xsl:variable name="identification">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ident/message"/>                                 
                    </xsl:variable>                       
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ident"><xsl:with-param name="ident" select="$identification"/></xsl:apply-templates>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="provisos/proviso"><xsl:with-param name="ident" select="$identification"/></xsl:apply-templates>

                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell> <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page" retrieve-class-name="footer-continued" retrieve-boundary="document" /> </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>           
            </fo:table>
```

Comment: Can you provide us snippet of code to see where you are using `<fo:retrieve-marker>`. But basically, a `retrieve-marker` can only be used in a page header or footer (`<fo:static-content>`).

Comment: okay 
if i put the marker in the page footer I get no Error Message but this is need the issue want to show my text in the table

Comment: Of course it will appear in the footer... A workaround that I suggest could be to set negative top margins for the *(to be continued)* text so that it appears higher in the page. But unless you use a commercial product such as Antenna House or RenderX which support `retrieve-table-marker`, I'm afraid you have no choice.

Comment: I checked my fop version i use 1.1 maybe the new fop version supports the table markeer

Comment: In https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html, it is documented that should it be **partially** supported starting from FOP 2.0.

Comment: As @potame said, FOP 2.0 partially supports table markers (I just tested it with a simple example); but _could you clarify a bit what you are trying to achieve_? Your code has the `fo:marker` inside the table footer, and the `fo:retrieve-marker` inside the table body, which seems strange ...

Comment: I want to archive a text output if the table goes on the next site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer)*

This example has dynamic table header and table footer, so it should cover your requirements:

- if the table fits in a single page, both table header and table footer are empty
- if the table is split over several pages

  - the table header is empty for the **first** page, and in the following ones it says "(continued)"
  - the table footer is empty for the **last** page, and in the previous ones it says "(continues on the next page)"
- tested with FOP 2.0 (older versions *did not* support table markers); due to FOP's current limitations, the *non-breaking space* `&#x00A0;` in the table header and table footer is a necessary "placeholder" (the header / footer dimensions are computed just once, without marker content)
- no formatter-specific extensions, so this could work with other formatters too ([XslFormatter](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/fo.htm#retrieve-table-marker) supports table markers; XEP has alternative workarounds)

**FO fragment:**

```
  <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
    <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>
    <fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="mc1" 
                retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting" 
                retrieve-boundary-within-table="table-fragment"/>
            &#x00A0;
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-footer>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="mc2" 
                retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending" 
                retrieve-boundary-within-table="table-fragment"/>
            &#x00A0;
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-footer>
    <fo:table-body>
      <!-- first row -->
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="mc1"></fo:marker>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="mc2">(continues on the next page)</fo:marker>
            cell1
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
      <!-- middle row -->
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="mc1">(continued)</fo:marker>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="mc2">(continues on the next page)</fo:marker>
            cell2
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
      <!-- ... other similar rows ... -->
      <!-- last row -->
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="mc1">(continued)</fo:marker>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="mc2"></fo:marker>
            cell9
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
```

Comment: Great example. Note that it will not work with RenderX XEP. We have chosen not to support retrieve-table-marker as of this time. We may in the future but have been able to workaround better (and much faster) solutions in most all implementations for folks.

Comment: I have noticed this feature in FOP : https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/extensions.html#table-continue-label. Is it available in FOP 1.1 or not?

Comment: @potame No, the `fox:continued-label` extension dated back to the older versions and is not available in FOP 1.1 and 2.0: [source, see last bullet point](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/upgrading.html#pre-1.0) _(to be honest I'm getting an error even with FOP 0.20.5, but maybe I'm just using it in the wrong position)_